# Difference between a path-component of a topological space $X$ containing $x_0$ and a path-connected subset of $X$?

Tags: general-topology

What is the difference between a *path-component* of a topological space $X$ containing $x_0$ and a *path-connected* subset of $X$?

I've found out that a path-component of $X$ containing $x_0$ is a subset with the equivalence relation that $x_0$ can be connected to any other point $y$ with a path. That is it's the set of points which can be connected to $x_0$ via a path.

So am I right claiming that a path-connected subset of $X$ is a stronger argument as it would be that every point can be connected via every other point by a path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are both path-connectible to $x_0$ then so is $a$ path-connectible to $b$ - path connectivity is a transitive relation (this is necessary for it to be even an equivalence relation at all). All path-connected components are path connected subsets, but they are also *maximal* path connected subsets - being a path component is in fact stronger than merely being a path connected subset.

For instance, the unit disc is a path connected subset of the Euclidean plane, but it is not a component - the only nonempty path connected component in the plane is the entire plane itself.

P.S. You should say “a stronger *condition*”, or something like that, rather than “a stronger argument”.

Comment: How many path components containing $x_0$ can there be? I think, you must write the not a...

Comment: @MehmetKırdar Hmm, no, not really. I only use “a” when referencing components in general

Comment: @FSrike Oops. I wrote my prev. comment in the wrong section. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

*"every point can be..."* no. That's the definition of $X$ being path connected. Imagine $X=B_1(p)\cup B_1(q)$ is a union of two disjoint open balls of radius $1$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$. Then, $X$ is not path connected; there is no path joining $p$ to $q$.

- The *path component containing $p$* is the open ball $B_1(p)$.
- Examples of *path connected subsets of $X$*: $B_1(p),B_1(q),B_{1/2}(p),B_1/4(q)$
  etc. There are infinitely many path connected subsets of $X$.

So, no , 'path-connected subset' is not a stronger condition.

Answer (score -1):

> So am I right claiming that a path-connected subset of $X$ is a stronger argument as it would be that every point can be connected via every other point by a path?

No, these are equivalent. If $a$ can be connected to $b$, and $b$ to $c$, then $a$ can be connected to $c$.

A path-component is a special path-connected subset. It is a **maximal** path-connected subset. Note that being path-connected is an intrinsic property of a space, while a path-component depends on the ambient space.

For example, let $X=\mathbb{R}$ be the standard real line with the standard Euclidean topology. Then $[0,1]$ is path-connected, just like $[0,10]$ and $[-\pi,\infty)$. But none of them is a path-component. None of them is maximal in $\mathbb{R}$. The only maximal path-connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

Another example is $X=[0,1]\cup(3,4]$. Here we have two path-components: $[0,1]$ and $(3,4]$ while many many more path-connected subsets. Note how $[0,1]$ is a path-component of $[0,1]\cup(3,4]$ but not of $\mathbb{R}$.